# Time consumed for creating a Promise object

Tags: javascript, performance, promise

It seems that when calling `Promise.resolve()` this Promise object is only created once and stored somewhere on the heap, and later when calling `Promise.resolve()` again, it does not take additional running time. I tried the following codes:

```
let outerStart = new Date().getTime();
Promise.resolve()
.then(() => {
    console.log(`outer check:\t${new Date().getTime() - outerStart} ms`);
})
.then(() => {
    console.log(`outer end:\t${new Date().getTime() - outerStart} ms`);
})
.then(() => {
    let innerStart = new Date().getTime();
    Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`inner check:\t${new Date().getTime() - innerStart} ms`);
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`inner end:\t${new Date().getTime() - innerStart} ms`);
    });
});
```

The result on console was like following:

```
outer check:    16 ms
outer end:      17 ms
inner check:    0 ms
inner end:      0 ms
```

, which means when calling `Promise.resolve()` for the second time, the new Promise object were created immediately. Did anyone discover the same and maybe have some explanations for this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: @caisah The question was, I thought when calling `Promise.resolve()`, it should take similar time to run, however it does not seem so. So I wonder if my guess that Promise object only has one instance is correct and would like to get confirmation from the community.

Comment: just compare them to see if its one instance or not

Comment: Add a `Promise.resolve()` _before_ your timing code to find out.

Comment: @Maximus Yes, I tried. I have assigned two variables to `Promise.resolve()` respectively and compared, while the result showed they were different.

Comment: @robertklep I tried to add another `Promise.resolve()` in the beginning, and it gives me a same result.

Answer (score 1):

- Nope! you get `0` milli-seconds , however it is not `0` microseconds.
- You can use `console.time` with `console.timeEnd` to get the execution time in **micro-seconds**

```js
console.time('outer_check');
console.time('outer_check_2');
Promise.resolve()
.then(() => {
    console.timeEnd('outer_check');
})
.then(() => {
    console.timeEnd('outer_check_2');
})
.then(() => {
    console.time('inner_check');
    console.time('inner_check_2');
    Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
        console.timeEnd('inner_check')
    })
    .then(() => {
       console.timeEnd('inner_check_2');
    });
});
```

Comment: It is built-in .. You are Welcome 

Comment: Regarding to the question, yes, it was not 0 microseconds, but 'outer_check' was much larger than 'inner_check' in your example, and 'outer_check_2' is much larger than 'inner_check_2' as well.

Comment: running this code in jsfiddle produces different results - in fact, the `_2` times are smaller! (not sure how that happens, overhead of console logging I suppose)

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI curious: do timers get auto garbage-collected if the promise gets rejected and `console.timeEnd()` never executes?

Answer (score 0):

By removing any timing variations caused by console.log - the results are quite different

```js
var t = (function() {
    var times = {};
    var starttime = (...names) => {
        var now = performance.now();
        names.forEach(name => times[name] = {start: now});
    }
    var endtime = name => times[name].end = performance.now();
    var showtime = () => Object.entries(times).forEach(entry => console.log(entry[0], (entry[1].end - entry[1].start) * 1e3 | 0));
    return {starttime, endtime, showtime};
}());

Promise.resolve()
.then(() => {
    t.endtime('outer_check');
})
.then(() => {
    t.endtime('outer_check_2');
})
.then(() => {
    Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
        t.endtime('inner_check')
    })
    .then(() => {
       t.endtime('inner_check_2');
    }).then(() => {
        t.showtime();
    });
    t.starttime('inner_check', 'inner_check_2');
});
t.starttime('outer_check', 'outer_check_2');
```

Comment: Is it? For me (using Node v7), the outer check timestamps are consistently about twice as large as the inner check timestamps, which matches the behaviour that I was seeing with the original code.

Comment: as opposed to 16 times in the original question? I was merely presenting code that eliminates `console.log` delays into the timing (I get outer being 5 times inner)

Comment: No, sorry, I meant using proper timing with `console.time()/.timeEnd()`, but with `console.log` included. That also consistently showed the outer checks taking about twice the amount of time as the inners.

Comment: this code wont even run in node - so I'm not sure what your comments even mean

Comment: oh, how odd, in node I see timing for outer being about 20 times inner!! not 2x, 20x!! - this doesn't answer a thing, does it :p

Comment: I should remove this answer then!!

Comment: with bluebird, the inner code is only 10x faster (and I thought bluebird was **more performant**) - and with my own Promise library, it's also about 10x, but both sets of numbers are 2x faster than bluebird :p

Comment: having said all that - I know why the outer is slower (not why so much slower though) - moving the outer start times to the END of the code produces only a 5x difference between outer and inner ... the reason why outer is *slower* than inner should now be obvious